# Function in python to return the first exact match from a column in a csv with an input string

Tags: python, pandas, csv, string-matching

I want to write a function in python that returns me the first exact match from a column in a csv and an input string.

This is the input csv. Drug product(s) list is the header. I want to check the 6 strings inside an input file(string) and the code should return the first exact matching name from the Drug product(s) list in the input string.

Keywords to be checked:

```
Drug product(s) list

solution for injection
suspension for injection
film-coated tablet
concentrate for solution for infusion
cream
modified-release tablet
```

Input string where keywords should be checked:

```
 This supplemental application, submitted as a “Changes Being Effected” supplement, proposes  
the revisions in the incubation scheme for routine environmental monitoring of swab samples of film-coated tablet Alpuzim 
with the incubation scheme for contact plates. Also submission for Alpuzim cream is pending.
```

The function should only return the first match inside the file which is film-coated tablet. The loop inside the input string should break as soon as the first match is found

This is what I have tried till now:

```
import csv
def first_Occurrence(string):
    with open('C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\.spyder-py3\\unique_final_drug_products.csv', newline='', encoding ='utf-8') as myFile:

        reader = csv.reader(myFile)
        for row in reader:
            product = row[0].lower()

    for i in range(len(string)):
        i = i.lower()
        if(string[i] == product):
            return i
    return ('string not found')


a = first_Occurrence('we have a solution cream for back pain')
print(a)
```

Comment: To check if a string contains a substring you can use the keyword `in`. `if search_string.lower() in csv_string.lower()`

Comment: How do I put it in the code in the following context

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

def first_occurrence(string):
    path = Path('C:/Users/Lenovo/.spyder-py3/unique_final_drug_products.csv')
    with path.open() as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if string.lower() in row[0].lower():
                return row


a = first_occurrence('we have a solution cream for back pain')
print(a)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. just need to change the line to  if row[0].lower() in string.lower():

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to solve your problem but [the logic to what you are looking for is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55278132/how-to-verify-username-and-password-from-csv-file-in-python/55278583#55278583)

```py
import csv

login = False
answer = input("Do you have an account?(yes or no) ")

if answer == 'yes' :
   with open('upassword.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
      csv_reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
      username = input("Player One Username: ")
      password = input("Player One Password: ")

      for row in csv_reader:
         print(row[0], row[1])
         print(username, password)
         if row[0]== username and row[1] == password:
            login = True
            break
         else:
            login = False
            break

   if login == True:
      print("You are now logged in!")
   else:
      print("Incorrect. Game Over.")
      exit()    
else:
   print('Only Valid Usernames can play. Game Over.')
   exit()
```